# Is it possible that my coated gas pipes have developed multiple leaks?

Tags: plumbing

My plumber is telling me my gas black pipes all have to be replace cause there are multiple leaks. Home was build in 1920s. There's a coating around the pipes, so is it still possible to get pin holes? Is it harder to redope/tape the joints? Or is the plumber just a con?

Comment: are the leaks in the pipe or at the threads and how did he test for the gas leaks?

Comment: "Multiple gas leaks" isn't a think you generally mess around with.

Answer (score 2):

The pipes are almost a hundred years old.  Leaking in multiple places means they are deteriorating.  Whether pinholes or at the seams I don't know.  But both options are bad.

They could check every inch of pipe and repair each leak.  But that won't help the parts that haven't quite failed yet.  So a month or two down the line you will have a new gas leak.  And the labor to do such repairs will probably cost more than ripping it out and installing new, known to be good pipe.

Replacing the whole thing is a very reasonable suggestion.  Especially with gas lines where a leak may very well kill you and your loved ones.

If you think the plumber is making the leaks up, get a second opinion.

Comment: Grant, you didn't address that part of the question that asks if this problem could be a con..false, fake, doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would get another opinion for the gas pipe leaks and ask to be shown where the piping is leaking. Gas piping rarely leaks even over a long period of years unless the piping was not installed correctly or has suffered from corrosion from water or a corrosive atmosphere.  If the whole gas line is suspect then the  gas line can be pressure tested by a licensed heating contractor or plumber.

Comment: yes, absolutely, get a second opinion.  While there is a small amount of condensate in natural gas, for there to be "multiple leaks" to justify replacing the whole system is suspect.  1920's is not a long time for a gas system.  Many, from the mid-1800's are still doing well.